# Swap the names/properties in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

Is there a more elegant way to do this in JavaScript?

```
function swapKey(obj, oldKey, newKey) {
  if (obj[oldKey]) {
    obj[newKey] = obj[oldKey];
    delete obj[oldKey];
  }
  return obj;
}
```

(I understand that it mutates the original object and is not functional and makes the returning of `obj` somewhat redundant and that's okay for this particular question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the idea is to change the key of a given pair. Few issues:

- Your code doesn't guard against existing keys. If my `newKey` is an already existing key, it would overwrite the existing value, and delete the old key.
- Like mentioned, mutation. Unless you're fully aware of the things that reference the object or have mechanisms in place to capture suddenly missing properties, you shouldn't mutate in-place. In the case above, if you accidentally delete an existing key another piece of code expects to exist, this will cause unexpected breakage.
- Your condition will return `true` for prototype members. Always do a `hasOwnProperty` check to ensure that you're only checking the instance, not the prototype.

Comment: Great points - thanks @Joseph the Dreamer. So there's no in-place way to rename the key of a key/value pair then?

Comment: @Guy There is, and you just did it. Just be wary about the consequences.